# How create Java code from Ecore metamodel without EMF jar dependences?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

Is possible to generate Java code from an Ecore metamodel, without the dependencies of EMF? Generate "clean Code" as if it were a generation from a UML model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to set the GenModel option "Suppress EMF Types" in the "Model Feature Defaults" section of the top-level node... There are are hole set of relevant options. Refer to the EMF book (2nd edition), for the complete details.

You can also use JET to generate you own Java code from the ECore model. Have a look at "[Metamodeling with EMF: Generating concrete, reusable Java snippets](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-emfmetamodel/)" for a rather detailed description.

Comment: "Suppress EMF Types" does not remove all the dependencies, however. I will look on the book, thanks

Comment: It could also serve to others: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/Recipes#Recipe:_Generating_Pure_API_With_No_Visible_EMF_Dependencies

Comment: Not everything can be removed using the EMF model editor. The #eSet, #eGet, etc methods have to be removed in the underlying template. The eInvoke method can be removed through setting "Operation Reflection" = false. The util package can be removed setting package level config "Adapter Factory" = false. Thee are others. Currently working out how to use List, not EList :-(

Answer (score 0):

Not everything can be removed using the EMF model editor. The `#eSet`, `#eGet`, etc methods have to be removed in the underlying template. The `eInvoke` method can be removed through setting "Operation Reflection" = false. The util package can be removed setting package level config "Adapter Factory" = false. There are other changes that can be managed from the genmodel config - see the EMF Modeling Framework book, section 12.3.1 for more details.

Note that "Suppress EMF Types" removes the EMF type from `EOperation` and `EReference` getters and setters only but not from the declared ivar or the constructor used in your getter (if list is null). These have to be changed in the template - Class.javajet to be specific. For details on how to replace the core EMF templates, see [using-dynamic-templates-in-emf](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/08/using-dynamic-templates-in-emf.html).

For the ivar, use `Feature#getImportedType`, not `Feature#getImportedInternalType`:

```
protected <%=genFeature.getImportedType(genClass)%> <%=genFeature.getSafeName()%>;
```

This line follows the comment section containing the following that is within the isListType test:

```
<%} else if (genFeature.isListType() || genFeature.isReferenceType()) {%>
  <%if (genClass.isField(genFeature)) {%>
/**
 * The cached value of the '{@link #<%=genFeature.getGetAccessor()%>() <em><%=genFeature.getFormattedName()%></em>}' <%=genFeature.getFeatureKind()%>.
 * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
 * <!-- end-user-doc -->
```

For the accessor, use something like the following to replace The EMF `EList` impl with an `ArrayList`:

```
<%=genFeature.getSafeName()%> = new <%=genModel.getImportedName("java.util.ArrayList")%><<%=genFeature.getListItemTy‌​pe()%>>();

instead of:
<%=genFeature.getSafeName()%> = new <%=genClass.getListConstructor(genFeature)%>;
```

Comment: It could be argued that if you are having to change the templates to this extent then you shouldn't be using EMF :-)